# How to copy a trigger from one table to another

Tags: mysql

There is a table users, after archiving (renaming) it creates a table users LIKE users_old. How to transfer triggers from users_old to users.

Refinement, how to copy a triggers from table users_old to table users.

```
CREATE TABLE  users_old (
    id INT(11),
    name VARCHAR(30) );

CREATE TABLE users LIKE user_old;
```

Comment: I need to create a table:
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
And copy all the triggers to the new table.

Comment: Have you got any code to show? What is users_old or users?

Answer (score 0):

With the following `SELECT` statement, you can generate the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement(s) for the trigger(s):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TRIGGER ', TRIGGER_SCHEMA, '.', TRIGGER_NAME, ' ', 
    ACTION_TIMING, ' ', EVENT_MANIPULATION, ' ON ', 
    EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, '.', 'users', ' FOR EACH ROW ', ACTION_STATEMENT, ';'
)
FROM information_schema.TRIGGERS
WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE = 'user_old';
```

Then, you can run the result of this statement to create the trigger(s) for the new, copied table.

Answer (score -1):

You can find old table triggers with this query and rebuild them

```
SELECT      ACTION_STATEMENT
FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
WHERE       TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'DbName'
AND         EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE = "tableName"
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: This wouldn't replicate all the properties of the trigger - for example, when to execute it.