# How to copy triggers from one table to another table

Tags: sql, mysql

The following query only copies column names, data types, indices and constraints. But I also want to copy the triggers, how can I do this?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_order_temp LIKE tbl_order;
```

Comment: See: [MySQL - Duplicate a Table WITH Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264051/mysql-duplicate-a-table-with-triggers) and [How to copy a trigger from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463020/how-to-copy-a-trigger-from-one-table-to-another) and [MySQL "CREATE TABLE LIKE" include triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145042/mysql-create-table-like-include-triggers)